# Redshift (Business Analytics)

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence, amazon-redshift

I am using Amazon student subscription for a  datawarehouse project. I have been able to setup redshift cluster and I am able to query tables via sql work bench. I need to perform BI analysis tasks on the data, the only option I found that was open source is Redash.
I am not being able to identify what to enter in "host" field required in the redash redshift setup. Plus, is there any straight forward way to perform that?

Comment: Can you provide more information, and any screenshots would help.

Comment: Redash's support helped me out. The host was in ODBC string. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're in the AWS backend and go to `Redshift -> Cluster -> Configuration`, you should see the **Endpoint** which should look like **asd.asdasda.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439**. When you remove the **5439** (which is the port) then you'll have to host you have to connect to.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Redash's support helped me out. The host was in ODBC string. Thanks.